# Taking photo and storing it directly to OneDrive/365

Tags: camera, storage

At work, we draw on white boards a lot and at the end of the session, we take pictures of the boards (with our personal camera phones) with a goal of putting the pictures on our intranet.

Whilst it's minor, having to plug my phone in to the computer via USB, find the relevant images, copy them to my computer and then add them to our Office 365 storage / OneDrive is just an additional process I'd like to remove.

I can't sync the DCIM folder because it would include personal pictures as well.

Is there way to always save images to OneDrive/365? I found http://www.uploadcamapp.com/ which is perfect other than it only uploads to Drive and Dropbox

It needs to be OneDrive/365 as that is what the business uses.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if OfficeLens does this, but it is slow and manual. With uploadcam the photo was just automatically uploaded where as OfficeLens asks you to choose where to upload on each photo taken